# MySQL installation on MAC

Tags: mysql, macos

I just installed mysql-8.0.12-macos10.13-x86_64.dmg on my Mac, and it said the installation successful. However, I can't find where the application is ... Where is my installed application? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to "System Preferences" (cmd + space and start typing)
you will see there a "MySQL".
From there you can start/stop mysql server.
If you need a client access, either use mysql workbench, either some other tool, but you can also try in terminal mysql -uroot -p (password provided at setup)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously, go to “System Preferences” and you will see MySQL in the bottom area:

[MySQL Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJluJ.png)

Click on it, and then in the MySQL window, click on the “Configuration” tab to see the directory locations for your MySQL installation.

[Configuration Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgP2i.png)

If you want to see these files in your Finder, be aware that they’re hidden files, so when you have finder open on your Macintosh HD folder, press “cmd + shift + dot” to show the hidden folders.

Also, if you want to actually interact with your MySQL installation, you’ll want to either install a graphical interface, like MySQL Workbench, or interact with it through the command line.

If you want to interact with it through the command line, you may need to first define the MySQL path in the paths file.  If this isn’t defined, you will get a “command not found: mysql.server” error when you try to run commands for SQL.